# Has there been any attempt to classify the countable ordinals that correspond to models of set theory?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, forcing

Let $S:=\{ \alpha\in \aleph_1 \mid \exists M, M \models ZFC \wedge M\cap \textbf{ORD} =\alpha \wedge |M|=\aleph_0 \}$.  Has there been any research into the properties of S?

In particular, I'm interested in the connection to Shoenfield Absoluteness.  Sense any two models of set theory containing the same ordinals agree on all $\Sigma_2^1$ and $\Pi_2^1$ arithmetical sentences, forcing is insufficient to prove independence of such statements.  It seems to me that the logical first place to start is exploring this S.  I've found a proof that this S is unbounded, but anything more seems incredibly difficult.

Comment: Note that the choice of metatheory matters here: $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone can't even prove that $S\not=\emptyset$, and it's moreover consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $S$ has exactly $17$ (say) elements. In my experience, for questions like this the default theory is $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "Every set is an element of some transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$" unless stated otherwise.

Comment: Separately, note that your $S$ can be rewritten a bit more snappily as $\{\alpha\in\omega_1:L_\alpha\models \mathsf{ZFC}\}$, so we can think specifically in terms of the $L$-hierarchy which helps simplify things.

Comment: @Binary198 You might find the above comments interesting